# Change x axis label names, format, and orientation (perpendicular to graph)

Tags: r

I can't help but feel like i am doing this in a more complicated way than needed. Any adjustments to make my code more parsimonious would be helpful here. Anyway, I would like to restore the spaces to my x axis labels (had to remove them to remove an error), I would like to get rid of the word "behavior" in my labels (the only reason they are in there are so that my code can recognize the words after behavior as separate categories), and i would like to rotate them so that they aren't overlapping

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
df <- structure(list(Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterSoundStart = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterSoundStart = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_CLAfterSoundStop = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterSoundStop = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChBeforeSoundStart = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChBeforeSoundStart = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterMMStartGesticulate = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStartGesticulate = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterPStartExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStartExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterPStartOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStartOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterPStopGesture = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStopGesticulate = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterMMStopExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStopExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChAfterPStopOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChAfterPStopOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChBeforeMMStartGesticulate = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChBeforePStartGesticulate = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChBeforeMMStartExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChBeforePStartExtension = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_HL_BehaviorChBeforePStartOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140),
                     Percent_NH_BehaviorChBeforePStartOther = c(0.970,0.870,0.830,0.670,0.360,0.000,0.370,0.710,0.140)),
                class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df_Percent <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:14,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(names= str_remove_all(names, "Percent_")) %>% 
  separate(names, c("Group", "Behavior"), sep = "_")

plot_Percent <- ggplot(df_Percent, aes(x = fct_inorder(Behavior), y=values, color=Group)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), size=1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))+
  xlab("Behavior",) + 
  ylab("Value") +
  theme_bw()

plot_grid(plot_Percent, labels = "AUTO")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the angle of your axis text you need yo change the parameter inside `theme()`, in this case:

```
plot_Percent+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]